# How to develop for AIR 2.7

Tags: actionscript-3, air

How I can develop AIR applications for version 2.7? I've downloaded the AIR SDK, but when I change application.xml to:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.7">
```

The compiler shows the error:

```
Invalid application descriptor: Unknow namespace: http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.7.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Add `target-player=11` to your compiler arguments

Comment: No, not work. I`m copy all files from AIR SDK folder to Flex 4.5 SDK folder, and still not work :(